# border radius code without jquery & PIE

Tags: html, css

i saw a code for border radius in ie(-8) but i cant find it.
evry where is only by jquery or `behavior: url(PIE.htc);`
for example for box shadow this code is:

```
/* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=7, Direction=140, Color='#d3d2d2')";
/*For IE 5.5 – 7*/
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=7, Direction=140, Color='#d3d2d2');
```

or for opacity:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=70);
```

who can help me for finding that code, please?

Comment: You want to get a rounded border in <=IE8 without using the workarounds that supports rounded border in IE8?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, IE8 does not support rounded corners natively. You have to use jQuery or a CSS3 filler.

Comment: what is the filter syntax

Comment: @sepehr2121: There is none for ie8.

Answer (score 1):

**So any version of Internet Explorer lower than 9 doesn't support rounded corners.**

Your options are:

1. Use rounded corner images, [nice plugin here.](http://www.generateit.net/rounded-corner/)
2. Use CSS3 Pie ([which you don't want to use](http://css3pie.com/))
3. Use a JQuery Plugin [(which you don't want to use as well)](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner)
4. An [IE CSS3 Plugin](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/) - which provides CSS3 selectors for IE6/7/8

Note that option 4 provides both box shadow and rounded corners.

Comment: You can use the CSS3 selector support in option 4 to provide box shadow. Didn't you have a look?